# Leakage Detection Circuit

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance

Leakage happens when the state of the system is no longer in the computational subspace that defines a qubit. In Preskill's notes on [Fault Tolerant Quantum Computation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9712048.pdf) (Pg 40), a circuit for leakage detection is mentioned.

Here is a picture of the circuit:

[image: leakage-detection-circuit]

I am confused as to why this circuit works - normally I would write the state at each step. However, in this case, I am not sure how these gates act on a leaked state.

My suspicion is that the NOT gates don't do anything and the CNOT essentially works if the state is $|1\rangle$ or higher. Is this correct? Why?

Comment: You can model leakage by introducing a third basis state $|2\rangle$ and making assumptions about how the physical implementation of the gates acts on this third basis state. It says the XOR (meaning CNOT) does nothing if the data has leaked. For the NOT gates, either they return $|2\rangle$ to the computational basis in which case it's no longer a leakage error, or they don't in which case the XORs act trivally and the ancilla measurement will return $|0\rangle$.